# How to Show/Hide a RelativeLayout in ListView ListItem on item click?

Tags: android, android-layout

In my xml I have:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFFFFF" android:id="@+id/listItemMainRelativeLayout">


    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/myFavourtiesPlaylistTextRelativeLayout"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <TextView android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"..... android:textColor="#000002"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"></TextView>
        <TextView android:visibility="visible" .... android:id="@+id/myFavouritesPlaylistDescription"
            android:textColor="#000006"></TextView>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/myFavourtiesPlaylistButtonRelativeLayout"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:focusable="false" android:focusableInTouchMode="false" android:visibility="gone">

        <ImageButton android:id="@+id/playListPlayButton"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="visible" android:background="@drawable/play_button"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:focusable="false" android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

My Java Code is:

```
public OnItemClickListener listOnItemClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position,
            long id) {

        if (previousSelectedListItem != -1) {

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                    "Hidding Position:" + previousSelectedListItem,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            RelativeLayout mainRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) v;

            RelativeLayout buttonsRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) mainRelativeLayout
                    .findViewById(R.id.myFavourtiesPlaylistButtonRelativeLayout);
            buttonsRelativeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ShowingPosition:" + position,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        RelativeLayout mainRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) v;

        RelativeLayout buttonsRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) mainRelativeLayout
                .findViewById(R.id.myFavourtiesPlaylistButtonRelativeLayout);
        buttonsRelativeLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        previousSelectedListItem = position;

    }
};
```

**Expected Behavior:** I want to make `myFavourtiesPlaylistButtonRelativeLayout` in the item visible once it is clicked.

**What is Happening:** `myFavourtiesPlaylistButtonRelativeLayout` of clicked item remain hidden, but a few other random items become visible instead.

Comment: why are you using onItemClickListener? this is for ListView. Create onClickListener() instead.

Comment: yes you are right I am using it in a listvew, I apologiize I did not mention that .

Comment: i'm not sure i understand this. Post your whole code.

Comment: In my listner i get the clicked view and then get its child relative layout to make it visible, It should make the view in clicked item visible. But it does not do that, it makes few other views visible on random indexes.

Answer (score 1):

I believe having a RelativeLayout inside of a ListView is the problem.  I have wasted 6h of my day today on a simmilar issues.

[ListView element not clickable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7923730/listview-element-not-clickable)

Try reading this thread, it should provide the fix.

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3414